# Ruby on Rails - How to set up Ahoy Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ahoy

Im setting up `Ahoy gem` into my application, but there are some options that I don't understand where to add.

*This is what I have done currently:*

*1)* Added `gem "ahoy_matey"` to my *Gem File* and ran `Bundle install` & restarted my server

*2)* Added `//= require jquery` & `//= require ahoy` to my `application.js`

*3)* Ran `rails generate ahoy:stores:active_record` and added new tables to my database by running `rake db:migrate`

I also have `ahoy.rb` in my **initializers** folder.

At this point I can see that `ahoy` is added in my application, but not sure how to do some stuff.

I want to add `Ahoy.cookie_domain = :all` & `Ahoy.visit_duration = 1.minute`, But I don't know where to add them

*AND* one other issue I have is that whatever page I go to is added to my `Visits` table *(PS: I haven't added any `JS` or `Ruby` code for tracking in any pages or controller)* and as I see it ,`ahoy gem` tracks all events/visits in my application. I only want to track events/visits on one particular action in my whole application, `posts#show` action and rest don't need to be added at all.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to add `Ahoy.cookie_domain = :all` & `Ahoy.visit_duration = 1.minute`, But I don't know where to add them

You add them in the initializer that you created (`./config/initializers/ahoy.rb`). This is precisely the purpose of files in that folder: Setting configuration values for the application to use.

> whatever page I go to is added to my `Visits` table [...] I only want to track events/visits on one particular action in my whole application

The [Gem's README](https://github.com/ankane/ahoy/blob/master/README.md#events) says:

> There are three ways to track events. [...] See Ahoy.js for a complete list of features.

So start there, and take a look at [`ahoy.js`](https://github.com/ankane/ahoy.js#events) if you need some more advanced configuration. The gem is very flexible - you just need to read the documentation and configure it as needed.

Comment: Thanks @TomeLord. `Visit_duration` works great, and I now manage to only track `posts#show` in my `ahoy_events`, but I still see `ahoy_events` are added and same with `visits`, but in my `ahoy_events`, it's `visit_id` is `nil`. This is what I added to my view: `- ahoy.track "Viewed post", id: @post.id`. What Im doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you still using `ahoy.trackAll();`? (Don't.) Have you restarted the server? (Do.) Is that view only being rendered by the `Posts#show` action? (You could also consider logging the event [in ruby](https://github.com/ankane/ahoy/blob/master/README.md#ruby), not JS.)

Comment: Thanks for reply @TomLord, In my `Posts#show`, I haven't added any JS, only `Ruby`: `<% ahoy.track "Viewed post", id: @post.id %>`. And yeah I have restarted my server and yes, that view is only rendered by `Posts#show` action. As I can see from my tables, `Ahoy_events` works as expected and only tracks from `Posts#show`, **BUT** my `visits` table, track all visits on all views in my application, like *homepage, dashboard, posts#new etc*

Comment: Ahh right, sorry - I'm with you now. Again, please just check the documentation -- at a glance, it looks like you could for example place [`skip_before_action :track_ahoy_visit`](https://github.com/ankane/ahoy/blob/master/README.md#track-visits-immediately) in the `ApplicationController`.

Comment: Thanks @TomLord. Just to double check and to see if its correct practice, Adding  `skip_before_action :track_ahoy_visit` into `ApplicationController` will prevent all actions to not track visits, which means no visits will be tracked, But what I did was to add `skip_before_action :track_ahoy_visit` to all controllers **BUT** in my `PostsController` I did: skip_before_action `:track_ahoy_visit, except: [:show]`, and can see that visits only for this action is added to `visits` table. Can I do this? Thanks again :)

Comment: Yes, that would work. Or, you could just place `skip_before_action :track_ahoy_visit` in the `ApplicationController` and `before_action :track_ahoy_visit, only: :show` in the `PostsController`. However, can I please request that any further issues be raised as new questions in StackOverflow rather than us having a continued discussion thread in these comments? :)

Comment: (Also, if you're ONLY using the `Ahoy` gem for this one tiny use case, then I'd seriously consider just writing your own implementation in that controller action rather than include the third party dependancy!)

Comment: Thanks a bunch @TomLord. I was thinking about the same thing but I need GEO and UTM tracking that `ahoy` does. You'r the man :)